# MySQL not returning each year

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to have this query show the empid and ordercount from each year. The only year being returned is 2006. The order table itself has a lot of orders ranging from 2006-2008.

```
select empid, year(orderdate) as orderyear, count(empid) as ordercount
from orders
group by empid
order by year(orderdate);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the order count for each empid and each year, you need to group by the year too:

```sql
SELECT   empid, YEAR(orderdate) AS orderyear, COUNT(empid) AS ordercount
FROM     orders
GROUP BY empid, YEAR(orderdate)
ORDER BY YEAR(orderdate);
```